# Regular expression for should NOT be numbers only and must allow all characters including line breaks

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regular expression for should NOT be numbers only and must allow all characters  including line breaks.

I tried the following cases:

1. `/[^0-9]/g;`

   In this case, if I enter line break it's not working then tried like below
2. `/^((?!www\.).)*$/`

   In this case, if I enter like this

   ```
   45454545
   45454545
   dfdfdfdfdfdf
   ```

   It's not working. I think here it is matching only in one line and not in entire paragraph.

Could you please tell me the regular expression for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
[\s\S]*?[^\d\n\r][\s\S]*
```

Comment: it can contain digit, It shoud not contain only digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^(?!\d+$).*$/s` .
This will match stuff like `abc`, `1a`, and `a1`, but not `123`.

Explanation:

```
^ # assert start of string
(?! # assert the string is NOT all digits:
    \d+ # match any number of digits
    $ # and end of string
)
.* # since the previous assertion did not fail, simply match all available text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i want to write this regular expression in angularjs like the following var bioPatterns = new RegExp(/^(?!\d+$).*$/s); but its not taking "s" which is in the last. if i put in "" its not working please tell me.

Comment: @Kumari: Javascript doesn't support the dotall (s) modifier. Use `^(?!\d+$)[^]*$` instead.